# (C) between and in functions - pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am writing a code and i'm getting a problem when i'm initializing a int that will be the length of a char pointer ( that's redirected to a string ).
Can someone tell me what did i do wrong?
I'm getting a error at "int length1".
thx for helpers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void func(char* p, int n)
{
    int length1;
    int length;
    int total;

}



int main(void){

    char str[100];
    int n;
    char* p;
    printf("Enter the N: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nEnter the string: \n");
    scanf("%s", &str);
    p = str;
    func(p, n);
    printf("%s", *p);
    system("PAUSE");
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &str);` should be `if (scanf("%99s", str) != 1) /* error */;` --- main issue is the `&`.

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting?

Comment: and the printf format specifier `%s` expects a pointer, not a `char`.

Comment: I'm getting the error:
Unhandled exception at 0x0F48FB53 (msvcr120d.dll) in q10.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000075.
but i will check my program again

Answer (score 3):

change this line.

```
scanf("%s", &str);
```

into

```
scanf("%s",str);
```

then while printing,

```
printf("%s\n",*p);
```

into

```
printf("%s\n",p);
```

And in your code there is no use in calling of that function. You are not doing anything.